# Wireframe editor with xml output for GUI generator

Tags: xml, user-interface, code-generation, wireframe

We develope with [OpenLaszlo](http://www.openlaszlo.org/) framework.

The idea is to have a tool to design UI components. The output should be an XML to use as a source for [code generation](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/05/05/cg-vel1.html).
The tool should be opensource.

What do you suggest?

Thanks in advance.

**Note**: I was searching previous questions, but I couldn't find any for our needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html) suits your need. It generates a file in XML format. I am not sure what wireframes have to do with your question. Still, you might want to look at [WireframeSketcher](http://wireframesketcher.com). Note that it's a commercial tool.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [softandGUI - UXToolbox](http://www.softandgui.co.uk). It's a high-quality wireframe tool that allows you to prototype and document your designs. I'm pretty sure it saves it's files in XML so could be just what you want. Note: It's note open source.